# GPU perfomance of updating ImageSource

Tags: wpf

I render image (`D3DImage` or `InteropBitmap`). I call `Invalidate` or `AddDirtyRect`. Then, system call submethods, the main tought of them is create scructures with values and call unmanagement methods. After this called `WritePostscript`, which update called property. So, each operation (i wrote early) after finish update Source, after this i see new image.
But, if my project have panels with not transparent Background, GPU use more resource every time, when update imagesource. If panels have background transparent, GPU use less resource. How i can use not transparent background and have nice GPU perfomance

Comment: Perhaps the GPU is optmized at a hardware level to use transparency? 

However, nornally I would have thought it would be the other way around, as working with transparency is a lot harder.

Comment: If you could post some example code, this would help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: In XAML:
`<Grid Background="Red">
            <Grid Background="Red"/>
            <Grid Background="Red"/>
            <Grid Background="Red"/>
            <Grid Background="Red"/>
            <Grid Background="Red"/>
            <Image/>
        </Grid>`
next you need create `var interopBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection(handle, width, height, PixelFormats.Bgr32, width * 4, imageBytesOffset) as InteropBitmap`
and set it as ImageSource of Image.

Comment: After this you need update your ImageSoource:
`Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    _interopBitmap.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, (Action)(() =>
                    {
                        _interopBitmap.Invalidate();
                    }));
                    CancellationToken.None.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30));
                }
            });`
Programm procexp.exe (View -> System Information -> GPU)

Comment: My PC show about 25%.
If i change xaml 
`<Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
            <Image/>
        </Grid>`
procexp.exe GPU show about 14%.

Comment: I would suggest editing your original question to add the XAML. Adding it to the comments means you might run out of space!

Comment: As you're new to StackOverflow, here are some tips on asking a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular, people are much more likely to help you if they can reproduce the problem on their own PC. Thus, adding some sample source code that would allow a motivated person to run the code on their own PC is a bonus.

Comment: After many time i decided use D3D9, Texture and etc. And i have very nice result. As result, for high perfomance rendering video ImageSource is not good solution

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. It would be great if you could post this as an answer, so anyone else can see that you found the solution.